# Image not fit in imageview frame under tableview, downloaded from URL using AsynchImageView

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, constraints, uitableview

- I use the AsyncImageView to display images in tableview that is
  downloaded from a URL (i used an imageView with a class as
  asyncImageView ).
- The images have all kinds of different sizes but i    need to display
  the image with a fixed size.
- I have used constraints    on my imageView but still it is behaving
  wrong.
- Image size is not    perfectly fit and when i click on a cell the
  image get a bigger size    before segue to another controller.

  How do i solve that ..? i tried    all my best

Comment: i think you directly set image to imageview like imageview.image = yourimage instead first set frame to imageView and then set image!

Comment: post some code also.so that one can easily understand your problem

Comment: i am setting the image url in tableview and asynch image view set image url method call .. which automatically load the image

Comment: i have used a custom cell and on this custom cell, i have used and imageView and set its class as AsynchImageView, and i am setting URL which is the property of AsynchImageView. this class then download image for me using the given URL

Comment: if the image is of different sizes then u sud use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill contentmode,that will serve ur pupose

Comment: i already done this, no result

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to scale to a fixed size you should use aspect fit scaling:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: it has been set as AspectFit for ImageView in storyboard

Comment: If you check the ImageView with the debugger after it has loaded the image is the scale mode still aspect fit? Also what constraints did you put on the ImageView?

Comment: i have used a custom cell and on this custom cell i have used and imageView and set its class as AsynchImageView, and i am setting URL which is the property of AsynchImageView. this class the download image for me using the given URL

Comment: widht, height, trailing, leading, top space

Comment: Then it seems you did everything as it should be done. Have you tried debugging the ImageView and checking which properties change after you click the table row?

Comment: this is beyond my imagination now :(